# React select checkbox that doesn't select option on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I coded this react-select that every option has a input checkbox, but it's not related to select itsefl, these checkboxes are for something else. But my problem is, now, when I click on this checkbox, my selected option in react-select changes, but it can't be like this. Is there a way to make clicking on checkbox seperate from clicking outside checkbox? Right now, when I click on checkbox, both checkbox checked changes and selected option. I tried z-index, but it doesn't work, any ideas?

That's how my select looks like
[image]

Code:

```
const optionLabel = option => (
    <div className="d-flex align-items-center pointer" style={{ background: 'transparent' }}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        className="pointer mr-2 available-module-checkbox"
        checked={currentTemplate.config.availableModules[option.id].includes(option.version)}
        onChange={() => handleAvailableModule(option)}
      />
      <span className="ml-2">{option.name}</span>
    </div>
  );

return (
<Select
        className="select-card"
        styles={colourStyles}
        getOptionLabel={optionLabel}
        defaultValue={getCurrentVersion(headerList, 'header')}
        onChange={e => {
          updateTemplateConfig('header', 'version', e.version);
        }}
        options={headerList}
      />
)
```